# Another way of saying positive or negative connotation?

Tags: word-choice

Is there another way of saying positive or negative connotation? e.g. The positive 'happy' contrasts with the negative 'sad'.

Comment: One way might be to stop thinking mathematically when speaking or writing English.

Comment: "to stop thinking mathematically when speaking or writing English" would be a huge mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think **[overtone](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overtone)** may fit:

> - (usually plural) an ulterior implicit meaning or quality; "overtones of despair"
> - an additional, usu. implicit meaning or quality.

(TFD)

Comment: I like this one.